# Pass element from option select populated from JSON to Controller

Tags: javascript, java

This my very first post, for several months I was able to find correct answer but this time I stuck.
I manage to create in JavaScript functions to create dependent - cascade drop-down-lists, when I choose Car Brand, then Models are served in next list and series in another accordingly.
But can not send the chosen positions to Java Controller. I`m open to criticism :-) I`ll be very grateful for any help.

## So the view looks as follows:

```html
    <form  action=make method="POST">
        <div class="item">
            <h3 class="item-title">Choose car</h3>
            <span class="year"></span>
            <select id="name" name="name" class="wrapper"  onchange="populateSelectModel(), populateSelectSeries()">
                <option   value="">--Select--</option>
            </select>
            <select id="model" name="model" onchange="populateSelectSeries()" >
                 <option value="">--Select--</option>
             </select>
             <select id="seria" name="seria">
                  <option value="">--Select--</option>
             </select>

            <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

```js
var selectBrand = document.getElementById("name");
var selectModel = document.getElementById("model");
var selectSeries = document.getElementById("seria");
var ourData;
     var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahmetozalp/auto-cars-makes-models-types/master/cars.json');
    ourRequest.onload = function(){
      ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
   
   var selectedBrand = populateSelectBrand(ourData);
   populateSelectModel();
   populateSelectSeries();
  };
    ourRequest.send();


     function populateSelectBrand(lista) {
       
         for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            
            selectBrand.innerHTML = selectBrand.innerHTML +
                '<option value="">' + lista[i].brand + '</option>';
           
        }
    }
    
  
    function populateSelectModel() {
        selectModel.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select model';
      
            var jakIndex = selectBrand.selectedIndex - 1;  
            var howlong = ourData[jakIndex].models.length;
                    
           for (var i = 0; i < howlong; i++) {
    
    
        selectModel.innerHTML = selectModel.innerHTML +
            '<option value="">' + ourData[jakIndex].models[i].title + '</option>';       
            }
           
        }

    function populateSelectSeries() {
            selectSeries.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select series';
          
                var jakiIndex = selectBrand.selectedIndex -1 ;  
                var jakiIndexModelu = selectModel.selectedIndex-1;
                var howlong1 = ourData[jakiIndex].models[jakiIndexModelu].types;
                             
               for (var i = 0; i < howlong1.length; i++) { 
                   
                
                selectSeries.innerHTML = selectSeries.innerHTML +
                '<option value="">' + ourData[jakiIndex].models[jakiIndexModelu].types[i] + '</option>';       
                }
              
            }
```

## ==================================================================
Finally when I can get via Controller the selected values from "name","model","series" I`m getting empty Strings (not null)
Java Controller

```
@Controller
```

@RequestMapping("make")
public class MAkeController {

```
@PostMapping
public String downloadMake(String name, String model, String seria) throws IOException {
    return ("download");
}
```

}

[screen shot from IntelliJ, while debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS7j9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While populating the `select` drop-down options, you are setting `option` tag **value** as empty string `value=""` in all the three functions as below

```
<option value="">
```

You need to set the respective `item` in `value` attribute of `option` tag too.

For example, similar to below in `populateSelectBrand` function:

```
selectBrand.innerHTML = selectBrand.innerHTML + '<option value="' + lista[i].brand + '">' + lista[i].brand + '</option>';
```

Do the same in other functions too.

When you do `form` `submit`, the **selected option `value`** will be sent to the server not the `label` displaying in thr UI screen.

Comment: Ohhhh Bosss Im very appreciated for this, finally Im getting how this is working !!! This worked form me Thanks again !

Comment: @Artur_Java_JS, hope this answer worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer to help others who are facing similar issues.